# Import NPM Script on Client Side Fails No Matter what steps are taken

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to import a simple npm script on the client side which is a function that takes in a single parameter: "name" and just returns Hello name.

After having installed the package via npm install I have made numerous attempts to import the script into my main.js file and nothing has worked:

Steps taken:

use var helloworld = require('@xxxxx/hello-world)

Result: Require is not defined

import helloworld from ('@xxxx/hello-world)

Result: Cannot use import statement outside of a module... Also putting type module into package.json has no effect.

Using browserify

Using Clientside-require

None of the above steps work.

Is it actually possible to just import the simplest of functions as an npm script on clientside?

This is the simple file structure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to import functions as npm scripts how are you running the above script ?

Comment: I am trying to use it either in the main.js file or as a script tag in index.html - whichever works best - see the file structure and function above

Comment: So you want to export the `Hello` function ?

Comment: Yes so it can be used in the front end main.js file

Comment: Still confused, let me ask you so there is an `npm` script you have created which you have published to `npm`, then in your frontend project you are trying `npm i <your_module>` and trying to require it in your `index.js`

Comment: Correct, but it won't let you use require or import.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> use var helloworld = require('@xxxxx/hello-world)
>
> Result: Require is not defined
> ```

Browsers have no native support for CommonJS modules. If you want to use a CommonJS module then you must transpile it with a tool like browserify.

---

> ```
> import helloworld from ('@xxxx/hello-world)
>
> Result: Cannot use import statement outside of a module... Also putting type module into package.json has no effect.
> ```

Browsers are not Node.js. *package.json* is not used by browsers.

To use an ECMAScript module in a browser use `<script type="module">`.

You also need to import from a URL. Browsers will not search `node_modules` for a module name.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) for more details and examples.

---

> Using browserify

Unless the module depends on Node.js-specific features (such as the `fs` module), browserify should work fine. There isn't enough information in your question to determine why it isn't working for you.

---

> Using Clientside-require

Ditto.